# I'm getting a segfault and can't seem to find it

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

The code below is segfaulting randomly and I can't seem to see what the problem it. Any help would be appreciated. I isolated it to this function using gdb and core files.

```
char* chomp(char *str)
{
   unsigned int scan_ind, curr_ind;

   scan_ind = curr_ind = 0;

   while(str[scan_ind])
   {
      if(str[scan_ind] != 0x0A &&
         str[scan_ind] != 0x0D)
      {
         if(curr_ind != scan_ind)
            str[curr_ind] = str[scan_ind];

         curr_ind++;
      }

      scan_ind++;
   }

   str[curr_ind] = 0;

   return str;
}
```

Comment: Are giving it a zero-terminated string?

Comment: Have you tried running it through valgrind when it segfaults?

Answer (score 4):

That code looks okay, at least at first glance. One possibility is if you pass in a string that's either not null-terminated, or one that's not modifiable (such as a string literal).

For what it's worth, your function can be simplified quite a bit, to something like:

```
char *chomp (char *str) {
    char *from = str;                         // This is the pointer for reading.
    char *to = str;                           // This is the pointer for writing.

    while (*from != '\0') {                   // Until end of string.
      if((*from != '\n') && (*from != '\r'))  // Transfer desired characters only.
          *to++ = *from;                      // Only increase write pointer if transferred.
      from++;                                 // Increase read pointer no matter what.
   *to = '\0';                                // Truncate string if necessary.
   return str;                                // And return the in-situ modified string.
}
```

That won't help you with non-null terminated strings or string literals but it's a bit shorter and more C-like.

Comment: The null terminator is implicitly checked in the `while(str[scan_ind])`

Comment: while(str[scan_ind]) implicitly checks for the null terminator, continuing until it finds the end of the string.

Comment: It's good practice to test only boolean values inside conditionals.  Even though `*from != '\0'` will most likely produce the same machine code as `*from`, the former makes it clear that a pointer-to-char is being tested for end-of-string.  Always choose readability over brevity, especially when there's no run-time cost.

Comment: Doesn't this implementation leak memory, only at most 2 bytes per string? (the `\r\n` that is removed will be inaccessible, as free will free `char*` until `\0`)?

Comment: @Beaks: no, it doesn't leak memory. If you've allocated 100 bytes, it doesn't matter _what_ you do with those hundred bytes, that's what you've got until you free it. Putting null characters into it may affect its behaviour when you treat it as a string but that's an entirely different level of abstraction to the memory arena management.

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks, I expected `free()` would free `char*` until `\0`, thank you you for clarifying my `C` naïvety (I also upvoted you.)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your input is a string literal (like chomp("carrot")) or a pointer to a string literal? The function will fail, in that case, because string literals are read-only, and you write to it.

If you are using a string literal as the input to this function, try copying it into a buffer, and then calling the function. Better yet, if possible, re-structure the function so that str is immediately copied into a dynamically allocated buffer, and then use that buffer throughout the rest of the function, and return it.

Comment: This is most likely the problem. He's probably trying to write to read-only memory.